# Are any dependencies included in a BizTalk exported application MSI?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Are any/all dependencies included in a BizTalk exported application MSI?

Specifically any referenced assemblies in the GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be if you add them to the Application in BizTalk Administrator before exporting the .msi.

When you do, be sure to check one of the "Add to the global assembly cache on MSI file import/install" options.